# Android Navigation Bar: How to always navigate to the main fragment when selecting an item in the navigation bar?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments

There is a main fragment that is attached to a menu item in the navigation bar.

There is a button in the fragment, when clicked, the next fragment opens via `findNavController().navigate(R.id.action)`

How can I make it so that when I click on the button on the navigation bar, I reopen the main fragment?

At the moment, nothing happens and I just stay in the opened child fragment.

---

*An example of such an implementation is in the YouTube application.  There is a "Subscriptions" button on the navigation bar, which leads to a fragment with channels that I subscribe to.  Next, you can select a channel and a fragment of the channel view will open.  And if you then click on the "Subscriptions" button again, the main fragment will open again.*

Comment: Maybe you can use a flag for that. Like, when user navigates to that child fragment then you change the flag value, so when the user clicks the button next time, you have your flag value to determine what to do next.

Comment: yeah keeping a boolean variable would do the work.

just put a if statement on the Click listener and check its value for doing the appropriate action. and set the boolean value from true to false or vise versa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand your problem correctly, but try `findNavController().popBackStack()` (it brings you back to previous fragment) or `findNavController().popBackStack(R.id.fragmentYouWantToGo, false);`(it brings you back to fragment with this id